# Loop a multidementional array not giving the desired results

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
<?php
Array(
    [Spain] => Array(
        [Barcelona] => 2[Madrid] => 4[Mallorca] => 10
    )

    [France] => Array(
        [Paris] => 1[Monaco] => 3
    )

)
?>
```

The desired results is:

PS: **3** is the **count** and the **16** is the **sum** of points per country.

```
Spain (3x|16) - Barcelona (2), Madrid (4), Mallorca (10)
France (2x|4) - Paris (1), Monaco (3)
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
foreach ($array_countries as $country => $cities_points)
{
    foreach ($cities_points as $city => $point)
    {
        echo $country . " (" . count($cities_points) . "x) - " . $city . " (" . $point . ")<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

The results of my code:

```
Spain (3x) - Barcelona (2)
Spain (3x) - Madrid (4)
Spain (3x) - Mallorca (10)
France (2x) - Paris (1)
France (2x) - Monaco (3)
```

I tried to **implode** and to get the sum, but it didn't work for me.

**PS**: I want to get all the cities of the one country on one line, then I will work on the **SUM**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Ken, I know. I just want to get all the cities on one line, then I will work on the sum. The first problem stopped me there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you are looking for `array_sum`:

```php
$array = [
    'Spain' => [
        'Barcelona' => 2,
        'Madrid' => 4,
        'Mallorca' => 10,
    ],
    'France' => [
        'Paris' => 1,
        'Monaco' => 3,
    ],
];

$output = [];
foreach ($array as $country => $cities_points) {
    $count = count($cities_points);

    // Sum all of the values
    $sum = array_sum($cities_points);

    // Keep track of each city
    $items = [];
    foreach ($cities_points as $city => $point) {
        $items[] = sprintf('%1$s (%2$d)', $city, $point);
    }

    // Put it all together
    $output[] = sprintf('%1$s (%2$dx|%3$d) - %4$s', $country, $count, $sum, implode(', ', $items));
}

echo implode(PHP_EOL, $output);
```

Output:

```
Spain (3x|16) - Barcelona (2), Madrid (4), Mallorca (10)
France (2x|4) - Paris (1), Monaco (3)
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/FQHQi

Comment: This has been updated, I see you want the cities all in one line

Comment: Hi Chris, your solution works perfect for me. Nice coding. Thanks a lot!